# ios launch image is displayed each time i open application after changing orientation

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate

I am observing a behavior. I am not sure if it is a normal behavior or not. My steps are as below :

1) start application by pressing application icon. it shows me launch image first and then displays rootviewcontroller.

2) I press home button. and my application goes in minimize state.

3) Now I change the orientation of the iPad and again tap to application icon. It again shows the launch image and then loads the rootview. If I do not change the orientation then it does not shows launch image next time I open the application.

Any suggestion or direction will be thankful.